# Condition which is false appears and disappears when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have if else condition , I know which one is true and must work when page is rendering but the false one works for very short time. How can i stop this.
I always see "Auction is over" and then the view changes but shouldn't I ever see this at all in the beginning? How does the wrong condition work and appear on the screen?

```
const [days, hours, minutes, seconds] = useCountdown(endDate);

const isFinished = (days + hours + minutes + seconds <=0);

let showTime = "";
let html = "";

if (pendingApiCall) {
    html = <Spinner />
} else {
    if (!isFinished) {
        showTime = `${days} days ${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes ${seconds} seconds`;

        html = (<>
            <span className="text-danger">{showTime}</span>

            {isLoggedIn && (!isOwner && (<div className="action my-2">
                <Input label='Enter your bid' name='bid' id='price' type="text" onChange={onChangePrice} error={bidError || samePriceError  } />

                <ButtonWithProgress className="add-to-cart btn btn-default" pendingApiCall={bidPendingApiCall || pendingApiCall}
                    text='bid on product' onClick={() => setModalVisible(true)} disabled={bidError || (price == null)} /></div>))

            }
            {!isLoggedIn && <Link to="/login" className="action my-2">Login to bid</Link>}

        </>
        )
    } else {
        html = (<span className="text-danger">"Auction is over"</span>);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the starting values of days, hours minutes, and seconds.   Plus changing const isFinished = (days + hours + minutes + seconds <=0); to  const isFinished = (days + hours + minutes + seconds) <= 0;   might help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `isFinished`, its value never change after the first assignation. It is possible init this with `true`.

You could create this as a state and modify it in a `useEffect` which dependencies are only `days, hours, minutes`. Avoiding type `seconds` to not render every second, but is not totally necessary.
When minute is less than 1 `days, hours` is equal to `0`, a `setTimeout` to call a function which toogle `isFinished` in 59 s, or another creative solution.

```
const [isFinished, setIsFInished] = useState(true)

useEffect( () =>{
   if(days === 0 && hours === 0 && minutes > 1)
      // setTimeOut to call a function
   else
      return;
},[days, hours, minutes]) // You can add the rest of them
```

That's my idea. But, maybe some other better approach can exist.